# Is receiving health insurance from one's company permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, fatwa, insurance

I would just like to know your thoughts on taking health insurance from your company (given that you have to pay a part of it). I know we are all mujtahids here.

From what I know the default ruling on insurance contracts is that they are haram given that there is an element of doubt in them (meaning you do not really know what you are buying or the exact amount of what you are paying for).

But given the high cost of health care (especially in the US), would this count as dururua (expiation because of hardship)?

*Jazak Allah khair for any insight.*

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell us what school of thought you have then based on that someone can answer. There are various answers to this question. However in a nutshell: Sunnis are more inclined to it being Haram. Shias are more inclined to it being non-haram. Yet they vary.

Though in each and every insurance contract, the way it's written and the conditions of the country you live are important. In Some countries not having insurance is extremely difficult. If you live in US and don't have insurance an Emergency room visit may cost you $2000-$10000. Or a long stay in the Hospital can cost you $50000 basically making you bankrupt.

I strongly suggest you ask your own Imam,leader of sect,etc.

Answer (score -1):

It isn’t considered as a haram act, since you pay a specified amount of money, then the institute give you some healthy services as a written contracts. Consequently as I said, it doesn’t seem to be a haram practice (although if you don’t precisely know what they are doing with the money ...). Besides, as you mentioned, it is counted as a law of a country that you ought to do it. (Although we ought not to do any haram law...).

Comment: If you can mention any authentic sources or references of some scholars whodo not consider it haram will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Insurance is not haram. It's more risky to not have insurance than it is to have insurance. You don't know the outcome of any investment you make, in fact if you did know the outcome that would be riba (unlawful profit/interest based on Islamic rules).